# How to convert this query into lamda expression

Tags: c#, linq, join, lambda

How to write the Convert this query into lamda Expression?

```
from lst in from employee in dbe.employees
            join ordermaster in dbe.ordermasters 
                              on employee.emp_id 
                              equals ordermaster.emp_id
            select new
            {
              emp_name = employee.emp_name,
              emp_id = ordermaster.emp_id,
              order_date = ordermaster.Order_date
            }
where EntityFunctions.DiffMonths(lst.order_date, dt) == 3
select lst;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Select List then you can use :

var x = UtAccuralLstForComp.Where(x => x.VendorName == Name).ToList();

**This will return List Of Object.**

If you want to Select onle one value then you can use :

var x = UtAccuralLstForComp.Where(x => x.VendorName == Name).Select(x => x.VendorNumber);

**This will return Only One Value.**

Answer (score 0):

First, welcome to SO!

I guess you are using LINQ-to-Entities and would encourage you to keep the syntax you currently use. When it comes to joins I personally believe it's much more readable. But *if* you want to convert your expression to lambda, this should be equivalent:

```
// models just for testing...
var employees = new List<Employee>()
{
    new Employee()
    {
        emp_id = 1,
        emp_name = "Name 1"
    },
    new Employee()
    {
        emp_id = 2,
        emp_name = "Name 1"
    },
    new Employee()
    {
        emp_id = 3,
        emp_name = "Name 1"
    }
};
var ordermasters = new List<OrderMaster>()
{
    new OrderMaster()
    {
        emp_name = "Name 1",
        emp_id = 1,
        Order_date = DateTime.Now
    },
    new OrderMaster()
    {
        emp_name = "Name 3",
        emp_id = 3,
        Order_date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
    }
};

var result = employees.Join(ordermasters, // Replace employees and ordermasters with your tables.
        e => e.emp_id,
        o => o.emp_id,
        (empl, ord) => new { Employees = empl, OrderMasters = ord })
    .Where(arg => EntityFunctions.DiffMonths(arg.OrderMasters.Order_date, dt) == 3)
   .Select(arg => new
   {
       emp_name = arg.Employees.emp_name,
       emp_id = arg.OrderMasters.emp_id,
       order_date = arg.OrderMasters.Order_date
   });
```

As far as LINQ goes, it should return the same result. If it converts to the same SQL is an entirely different thing.